# Advert delivery via Javascript document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an advert delivery method and am try to do it through an external Javascript/jQuery page.

I have this so far, but I have some issues with it

```
$.get('http://url.com/ad.php', {
    f_id: _f_id,
    f_height: _f_height,
    veloxads_width: _f_width
}, function (result) {
    var parts = result.split(",");
    var path = parts[0],
        url = parts[1];
    document.write('<a href="' + url + '" target="blank"><img src="' + path + '"></a>');
```

I can see the page load, but then after the code above is loaded, it creates a new page with just the advert on it. Is there anyway I can write it onto the page where the code was put?

And this is the script web masters put on their websites to include the adverts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _f_id = "VA-SQ2TDEXO78N0";

var _f_width = 728;

var _f_height = 90;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/cdn/addelivery.js"></script>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is ad.php on the same domain as your script? if it's not have a look at [this article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.fr/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

here is a code you could use in your html page, where you want the ad to be inserted:

```
$.get('http://url.com/ad.php', 
    { f_id : _f_id, f_height : _f_height, veloxads_width : _f_width }
).success(function(result) {
    var parts = result.split(",");
    var path = parts[0], url = parts[1];
    $('body').prepend('<div id="ad_id"><a href="'+url+'" target="blank"><img src="'+path+'"></a></div>');
});
```

the selector (body here) can be an id, a class, ... (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). You can also use prepend() or html() instead of append, to insert the code where you want ;)

Comment: Could the script create an element? Like <div id="ad_div"></div> or something and then post it into there.

Comment: yes. you can do $('yourSelector').append('<div id="ad_div"><a href="'+url+'" target="blank"><img src="'+path+'"></a></div>');

Comment: Ive added a new bit for how the user includes the advert

Comment: it's not the same, that's why I asked you if the js script was on the same server than the html page. Because this is a cross-domain request.
You should have a look at [htt access control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) and have a look at [this article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.fr/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Comment: Both the javascript and php code is on a separate server, the js that is included into the web masters page is returning the results, i just need a way for it to put the image onto the page.

Comment: so $('yourSelector').append()/.prepend()/.html() can do it. It depends if you want to let the webmaster choose where he wants to insert it. You could declare a new variable, like 
    var selector = "#ad";
he could change. And then you would have to do
    $(selector).append()
Do you have any problem with that?

Comment: The web master can only change the size, could you write something in your answer that i can try, then i will accept and vote it up.

Comment: like i told you, I can't do it for you. It depends of where you want to put your ad on their website (top banner, right banner, ...). I changed my initial code to insert your ad at the begining of the body. you could use css too.